# Split the height of the screen to body and footer

Tags: html, css

I need to split the screen to 2: body (around 90% of the screen) and footer (around 10% of the screen - fixed on bottom).
The footer should be transparent and the body should have a lot of text so would be a vertical scroll bar.
My problem is that the body's height isn't 90% of the height (but 100%) so I can see the text behind my footer.

How can I fix it?
Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jfew5s/) that shows my problem.

And the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
    texttext<br/>text<br/>text
</div>
<div id="footer">
    this is footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#body{
  height:80%;
}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your heights accordingly, but all you need is (CSS):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96jfew5s/4/

Comment: Your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jfew5s/3/) with a bit more of text. It does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I must have messed up when updating the fiddle. I fixed it

Comment: The fiddle and the answer aswell :) You are most welcome.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
body{
  margin: 0
}

#body{
  height: 90vh
}

#footer{
    height:10vh;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}

#body,#footer{
  display: block;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll

}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    texttext<br/>text<br/>text
</div>
<div id="footer">
    this is footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your parent (`html` and `body` tags) also to 100% of the height because if not you cannot set percentages to their childs (they try to get the percentage of their parents). Then, you can set your `overflow-y: auto;` to get the scroll in your `body` div.

Also, change the appropiate height to both `body` and `footer` divs.

**Note:** I would recommend you to change the name of your `body` div to other name that will not be related with reserved words to avoid confusions.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#body{
  height:90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>
</div>
<div id="footer">
this is footer
</div>
```